# how to convert this String to Decimal

Tags: sql, impala

i have this String '`5666,232343`' and i want to convert it to Decimal, i use `cast('5666,232343' as decimal(7,5))` but it returns `NULL` value.
Do you know why it doesn't work with CAST

Comment: how much do you think this is 5666,232343?

Comment: have you tried replacing , (comma) with a . (dot)

Comment: remove comma or replace comma with dot and try again

Comment: combine the answers below.  Replace the comma with a period and then you have a datatype issue that 5666.232343 will exceed the data type's max value which would be 99.99999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to a decimal that can hold the value of 5666.232343.
  `DECIMAL(7,5)` allows numbers in this format: ##.#####.  The biggest number you can have then is 99.99999.  You also need to take the comma out and replace it with a period:

```
SELECT CAST('5666.232343' as decimal(16,6)) AS [DecimalValue]
```

Comment: add the replacing of the comma in his number to this answer and it will be complete and the best

Comment: Why did you choose DECIMAL(16,6) instead of DECIMAL(10,6)?  ##.##### makes sense to me as DECIMAL(7,5), so why wouldn't you want DECIMAL(10,6) for ####.######? 10 total and 6 to the right of the decimal. From the appearance of other answers, it looks like DECIMAL(16,6) is the correct one for ####.###### and not DECIMAL(10,6). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Zorkolot is right. The current precision and scale that you've used is not sufficient for the value you've provided.

If you're using **SQL Server 2012 or higher** and you want to keep the comma in the value, then you can use the **TRY_PARSE** function and set a **culture**. It will return **NULL** if it encounters an error instead of not completing the statement and returning red text. This also allows you to add basic error handling to the statement, if you wanted, by getting failed conversions to return the value of zero. For example:

This is your original query (which is currently erroring) with my error handling fix:

```
select coalesce(try_parse('5666,232343' as decimal(7,5) using 'en-GB'),'0') as [DecimalValue]
```

This is the same thing as above but I've amended the decimal precision and scale so that the value is successfully converted:

```
select coalesce(try_parse('5666,232343' as decimal(16,6) using 'en-GB'),'0') as [DecimalValue]
```

This should prevent you having to perform a **REPLACE** either manually or by using the SQL function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the comma.  In some databases, some of the functions are not as internationally-sensitive as (I think) they should be.  So try:

```
cast(replace('5666,232343', ',', '.') as decimal(7, 5))
```